# How to reference a method in another Ruby code file?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby code file (somelogic.rb) that contains several methods and classes, located in say, /home/user/code. Now I'm writing another class in the same directory and would like to reference to the methods and classes in somelogic.rb. How do I do that? I greatly appreciate any input.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 1.9 or later, this is the simplest way to do it:

```
require_relative 'somelogic'
```

If you want your code to work in 1.9 and older versions of Ruby, you should do this instead:

```
require File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), 'somelogic'
```

Whichever line you choose, you should put it at the top of your ruby file.  Then any classes, modules, or global variables defined in somelogic.rb will be available to your program.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the scenario:

```
/home/user/code/somelogic.rb
class MyMath
  def self.sin(number)
    ...
  end
end
```

You want to use the methods `sin` in your other file `mylogic.rb`.

Depending on the version of ruby, do one the following:

```
Ruby 1.8.x
require "somelogic"
class OtherThings
  def some_method
    MyMath.sin(42)
  end
end
```

The use pattern is for all ruby versions the same, but the require statement may be different.

```
Ruby 1.9.x
require_relative "somelogic"
```

or variation

```
Ruby 1.9.x
require "./somelogic"
```

The first variation works all the time, the second one only if you call `ruby mylogic.rb` in the directory where `mylogic.rb` and `somelogic.rb` are located.

If you want to load files from that directory from a starting point located in another directory, you should use:

```
Ruby 1.8.x and Ruby 1.9.x
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

This expands the load path of Ruby. It reads the (relative) path of `__FILE__`, gets its directory, and adds the (absolute) path of that directory to your load path. So when doing then the lookup by `require`, the files will be found.

Comment: There is an important difference between `require './somelogic'` and `require_relative 'somelogic'`. The latter looks for a file *relative to the script itself*, while the former looks in the current working directory. Imagine we are in a directory called "project" and we run the Ruby program "scripts/do_the_thing.rb". If "do_the_thing.rb" uses `require_relative`, it will look for "project/scripts/somelogic.rb". On the other hand, if we'd written `require './somelogic'`, it would look for "project/somelogic.rb".

Comment: Adding on to what Chuck said, it's bad to do `require './somelogic'` because that makes an assmuption about the current working directory of the ruby interpreter, so it makes it hard to reuse your code in other projects.

Comment: But it is the only possibility you have if your files are not all the time in the same relation in the file system. Else `require_relative` is the better one (which does not exist it Ruby 1.8.x).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Ruby's require keyword](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require)

Answer (score -3):

In second file (say otherlogic.rb) write require '/home/user/code/somelogic.rb' on first line.

Comment: Please, don't do that. Your code will not be portable at all.

Comment: I know I was just being sure the file would be included (1.9.2 has some issue with 'require'). If you are in same directory you will just need require 'otherlogic.rb'