# Ruby: How to refer to classless script while using Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am new to Ruby, just picked it up last week. Currently using Ruby 2.0. Thus far I've just been looking up methods and googling for problems I've run into, which has been going well, but now I've stumped onto something that google does not seem to have an answer for.

I have a script that pulls data via open-uri and processes that data (let's call it pullrequest.rb). I now have to write tests for that. When I wrote pullrequest.rb I did not think it made sense to make it a class, and right now I am not sure if I can make it a class. It's very long, takes arguments, has a wrapper script to call it, etc.  However I did define methods inside pullrequest.rb.

So you can use Test::Unit to make assertions about your work, but it always seems there is a class inside the .rb you're testing. So you can write an assertion like:

`assert_equal("Kei", KTest.new.greeting("hi"))`

if the script you're testing has a class KTest and a method greeting inside KTest. But how would you refer to methods in a script like pullrequest.rb, where there is no class? I have tried Kernel.greeting, Object.greeting, just greeting itself (I was desperate to try anything of which I could think before asking for help). I read about those [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/86223).

I have added the "require_relative" bit mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116079/how-to-reference-a-method-in-another-ruby-code-file) and since they are in the same folder, I do not think the issue is that the test script can't find the classless script.

I'd appreciate any bit of enlightenment. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I would suggest a refactoring to turn your script into a class (which is then instantiated and called in your wrapper script). This will let you encapsulate the methods you've created within the class, allow them to be tested, and make life easier for you. In general, it's expected in Ruby that everything should be within a class (which is why, as you found out, the methods you create are implicitly in a class despite you not declaring one yourself).

An easy to way to start this would be to just wrap your existing script into a `run` method of a class, and include the other methods you've written into the class as well so they can be accessed from the new `run` method.

```ruby
class PullRequest
  def initialize(*arguments)
    # Take the arguments from your wrapper/caller script and turn them
    # into instance variables as necessary
    @arg1 = ...
  end

  def run
    # all the script code you currently have
  end

  # put the other methods you defined within the class as well:

  def method1(...)
  end

  def method2(...)
  end
end
```

Then you can update your wrapper script to call your class:

```
# pullrequest_wrapper.rb
PullRequest.new(*ARGV).run
```

I'm assuming that the arguments you mentioned are coming from the command line, hence `ARGV`. Note that `*` is the "splat" operator, which in this case turns an array into a list of arguments.

You can then further refactor to make your class easier to test by doing things like splitting up run into smaller methods, turning some of your existing methods into privates as necessary, splitting up responsibilty into additional classes, etc.

Comment: I ended up having to make it into a class after all. It wasn't so hard, just a bit of a setback. Thanks for the tip about the *ARGV!