# How do I run `require_relative` in a loop?

Tags: ruby

Here's `main.rb`:

```
(1..10).each{|x|
  require_relative 'script.rb'
}
```

Here's `script.rb`, which is in the same directory:

```
p "HELLO WORLD"
```

When I run `main.rb`, it prints "HELLO WORLD" only once.

Why? And how do I get it to print once for loop passthru?

Comment: Not a Ruby expert, but I suspect `require_relative` prevents you from loading the same file multiple times.

Comment: @neverendingqs Seems like it. Any way around this?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea - what are you trying to do?

Comment: `require_relative` should prevent multiple imports - it prevents you from causing problems like defining the same class twice.

Comment: @neverendingqs I only wanted to run the code from `script.rb` multiple times. I could move it into `main.rb`. There's no pressing need for the code to be in separate files.

Comment: Do that or define a method in `script.rb`. `require_relative` allows you to run code defined in other files.

Answer (score 3):

`load`allows re-loading, `require` and `require_relative` do not:

```
(1..10).each{|x|
  load 'script.rb'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the code you want to run to `main.rb` or define a method inside `script.rb` so you can call it from `main.rb`.

More details: [How to reference a method in another Ruby code file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116079/how-to-reference-a-method-in-another-ruby-code-file)

Reason not to use `load` in this scenario: [When to use `require`, `load` or `autoload` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804297/when-to-use-require-load-or-autoload-in-ruby)

Comment: The sensible thing to do.